# Динамически изменяющийся элемент хеша

Tags: ruby

Должен создаваться хеш значением последнего элемента которого будет сумма всех значений предыдущих элементов, к примеру:

```
hash = { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Deere', full_name: 'John Deere' }
hash1 = { first_name: 'John', middle_name: 'Francis', last_name: 'Deere', full_name: 'John Francis Deere' }
```

Возможно ли задать эти параметры при создании хеша, к примеру как-то через интереполяцию, или же нужно только применять к хешу методы, и если нужно - то как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Почему именно хэш, а не объект с обычными атрибутами? Там бы это был просто метод. Не, Ruby достаточно гибок, чтобы и в хэше оформить подобное, но надо ли вам это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
hash = { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Deere' }
hash.merge({:full_name => hash.values.join(" ")}) #=> full_name: 'John Deere'
```

Comment: В прошлых версиях Ruby элементы хеша не имели строгой упорядоченности, и я бы не рекомендовал на нее полагаться. Лучше сделать `{ name_parts: {first_name: 'John', middle_name: 'Francis', last_name: 'Deere'}, full_name: 'John Francis Deere' }` с допущением, что `full_name` может идти как вторым, так и первым.

Comment: Хотя по меньшей мере с Ruby 2.0 (который уже давно штатно не поддерживается) в документации к `Hash` явно указано, что значения в хэше будут перечисляться в порядке вставки, это довольно глубокая особенность, не относящаяся к природе этого контейнера; в отличие от, например, массива.